# How to add text in pie react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pie-chart

I am creating a Pie chart in my application and using "react-native-pie". I am able to create the chat like donuts, but I have to write the text also. I have to add text for all 3 data. It should come inside the color not in the center or donuts.

How can I do that?

```
                 <Pie
                    radius={70}
                    innerRadius={30}
                    strokeCap={'butt'}
                    sections={[
                      {
                        percentage: 30,
                        color: '#C70039',
                         Text:'Abhi'
                      },
                      
                      {
                        percentage: 30,
                        color: '#404FCD',
                      },
                      {
                        percentage: 40,
                        color: '#EBD22F',
                      },
                    ]}
                    strokeCap={'butt'}
                  />
```

Comment: the solution ih this link wors for me:
"https://github.com/genexu/react-native-pie-chart/issues/21" https://github.com/genexu/react-native-pie-chart/issues/21